# Nginx: https "not secure" but ` openssl s_client -connect <server_name>:443` works

Tags: nginx, https, openssl, nginx-config

Having followed the instructions on [this page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-22-04)  and configured `nginx` for exclusive https  connections, testing it from the command line (`openssl s_client -connect <server_name>:443` with a "GET /" request) works both from the server and from a remote machine. However, on both trying to access the server from a browser with `https://<server_name>` produces:

- on the local machine (with Midori): "Unacceptable TLS certificate";
- on the remote machine (with Chrome): "Certificate is not valid".

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: (0) this is not a programming or development question (1) if by saying s_client 'works' you means 'is able to send a request and receive a response', that does NOT establish the certificate is valid; see NOTES in the man page on your system or [on the web](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/openssl-s_client.html#NOTES) (2) dhparam 4096 is at best a waste of time and will cause some clients to fail if using TLS1.2 (or lower, but that's rare) _and_ not using ECDHE (also rare) but if you are indeed using Ubuntu 22.04 it has OpenSSL 1.1.1 which supports TLS1.3 and that ignores dhparam ...

Comment: ... (3) a self-signed cert is indeed not trusted by any proper client (i.e. excluding `s_client`) and the page you link even says so; moreover putting server identity _only_ in CommonName (CN) and not SubjectAltName (SAN) is more than 10 years out of date and doesn't work (at all) with Chrome (for several years) or Firefox (recently) and probably more soon if not already (I don't know about Midori)

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085. I'm more than familiar with Linux but entirely new to SSL and https -- I'm glad I came this far already... Your comments suggest I was taking guidance from outdated information. Please, can you refer me to the today's best information available? Many thanks!